# Calculate while excluding -1's

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an extremely large file of  tab delimited values of 10000+ values. I am trying to find the averages of each row in the data and append these new values to a new file. Howvever, values that weren't found are inputted in the large file as -1. Using the -1 values when calculating my averages will mess up my data. How can i exclude these values? 
The large file structure looks like this:

```
"HsaEX0029886"  100 -1  -1  100 100 100 100 100 100 -1  100 -1  100
"HsaEX0029895"  100 100 91.49   100 100 100 100 100 97.87   95.29   100 100 93.33
"HsaEX0029923"  0   0   0   -1  0   0   0   0   0   9.09    0   5.26    0
```

In my code Im taking the last 3 elements and finding the average of just the 3 values. If the last 3 elements in the row are 85 , 12, and -1, I need to return the average of 85 and 12. Here's my entire code:

```
with open("PSI_Datatxt.txt", 'rt') as data:
    next(data)
    lis = [line.strip("\n").split("\t") for line in data]        # create a list of lists(each row)
for row in lis:
    x = float(row[11])
    y = float(row[12])
    z = float(row[13])
    avrg = ((x + y + z) / 3)
    with open("DataEditted","a+") as newdata:
        if avrg == -1:
            continue    #skipping lines where all 3 values are -1
        else:
            newdata.write(str(avrg) + ' ' + '\n')
```

Thanks. Comment if any clarification is needed.

Comment: so if a line is 10 values, and two of them are -1, what do we do? replace -1 with 0 and do avg = sum(row)/10, or do we ignore them and do avg = sum(row)/8?

Comment: Your indentation is off. Also, why do you only take one value from each row?

Comment: 1) you don't need to `seek` the file after opening, it already is at the beginning; 2) there's no need to close the second file as the `with` clause'll do that for you; 3) your indentation's probably off as in its current state your code only computes the average for one row

Comment: the indentation is off. Sorry that happened when i was copying the code into the text box. Like i said Im  just trying to ignore the -1's. so if we have 3,4,5,-1, i want to take the average of 3,4, and 5. 
I will try to edit to correct the indentation...

Comment: You probably want to store your data in a `numpy` array and replace -1 with NaN and you'll then be able to use `np.nanmean` that calculates mean while excluding NaN

Comment: Thank you everyone, I guess I'm still a beginner at coding so I will try to put these answers into my code and once my code works I will accept the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   data = [float(x) for x in row[1:] if float(x) > -1]
   if data:
      avg = sum(data)/len(data)
   else:
      avg = 0 # or throw an exception; you had a row of all -1's
```

The first line is a fairly standard Pythonism... given an array (in this case  row), you can iterate through the list and filter out stuff by using the for x in array if condition bit.

If you wanted to only look at the last three values, you have two options depending on what you mean by last three:

```
data = [float(x) for x in row[-3:] if float(x) > -1]
```

will look at the last 3 and given you 0 to 3 values back depending on if they're -1.

```
data = [float(x) for x in row[1:] if float(x) > -1][:-3]
```

will give you up to 3 of the last "good" values (if you have all or almost all -1 for a given row, it will be less than 3)

Comment: x > -1 will ignore valid negative data.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ the sample data at least only had -1 and non-negative numbers and I dislike doing float(x) == -1 .  For OP: going to edit to explain a little more, and also for your get last values question

Comment: This one worked great thank you so much! This is actually for a report im doing with my school do you know if ill be needing to site your work??

Answer (score 1):

Here is it in the same format as your original question. It offers you to write an error message if the row is all zeros, or you can ignore it instead and write nothing

```
with open("PSI_Datatxt.txt", 'r') as data:
    for row in data:
        vals = [float(val) for val in row[1:] if float(val) != -1]
        with open("DataEditted","a+") as newdata:
            try:
                newdata.write(str(sum(vals)/len(vals)) + ' ' + '\n')
            except ZeroDivisionError:
                newdata.write("My Error Message Here\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
import csv


def average(L):
    L = [i for i in map(float, L) if i != -1]
    if not L: return None
    return sum(L)/len(L)


with open('path/to/input/file') as infile, open('path/to/output/file', 'w') as fout:
    outfile = csv.writer(fout, delimiter='\t')
    for name, *vals in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t'):
        outfile.writerow((name, average(vals))
```